# How to set a fixed width to a single column in jQuery datatables

Tags: html, jquery, css, datatable

In the datatable im having, i have a column that may be included long strings. So i need to set a fixed width only to the column (column "Reason") so the table is not much distorted.

```
<div class="report-container">
  <table id="reportTable" class="display compact">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Visit</th>
        <th>Reason</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="report-table-body">
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

```
   $('#reportTable').DataTable({
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "bFilter" : false,
    "ordering": false,
    "paging": false,
    "lengthChange": false,
    "lengthMenu": [ 1000, 2000, 5000 ],
    "scrollResize": true,
    "scrollX": true,
    "scrollY": "72vh",
    "scrollCollapse": true,
    "ajax": {
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json",
        url: "/report-data",
        data: function (json) {
            console.log(json);
            params.draw = json.draw;
            params.page = json.start;
            params.size = json.length;
            return JSON.stringify(params);
        }
    },
    "columns": [
        {data: "startDate"},
        {data: "visitNumber"},
        {data: "reason", width: 30}
    ]
});

<style>
  .report-table-body {
      white-space: pre;
   }
  .report-container {
      margin-top: 50px;
  }
</style>
```

In here even though the width is specified inside the `columns` its not applied. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: `table{
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  clear: both;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  table-layout: fixed;
  word-wrap:break-word;
}`

Comment: do this doesn't fix it